# How to fix cannot link SDL2 image on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

Hi I search it up on how to do it and I did it:

```
c_cpp_properites.json:


{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/Library/Frameworks/Headers"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++98",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

But i want to add SDL2_image too but i dont know how to do it so can someone please help me.

Comment: What is the issue? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I include the SDL2 path and it work but it didnt work for SDL2_image

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a bit more code, and what the error was?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok i willlllllll

Comment: not now tho gtg. do something

Comment: idk how to edit

Comment: There should be a button below the post.

Comment: ok lemme seeeeee

Comment: nope didnt see anything

Comment: It's right below the post contents. https://ibb.co/njNz9kv